# How does Wolfram Alpha get $\displaystyle\int\dfrac y{\ln y}dy\gets\operatorname{Ei}(-2\ln y)+c$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Now this goes back when I was trying to solve the differential equation$$y'y=\ln y$$which is a first order nonlinear ODE. Now, I was able to get this integral out of it:$$\int\dfrac y{\ln y}dy=x+c_0$$however it was there that I got stuck, since even though I know that I could probably evaluate the integral using a change of variables, I'm not sure which one to use. I had originally tried $u=\ln y$, which then $e^u=y\implies e^udu=dy$ and then the integral becomes$$\int e^u\cdot\dfrac{e^u}{u}du=\int\dfrac{e^{2u}}{u}du$$although now I don't know how to continue from here. WA gives$$\int\dfrac y{\ln y}=\operatorname{Ei}(-2\ln y)+c$$but I'm unsure how it gets that result. So my question is:

##### How does WA get $\int y/\ln(y)dy=\operatorname{Ei}(-2\ln y)+c$?

Comment: Substitute $2u=r$ and factor out constants

Comment: $u := \log y$ and 6.2.6 of https://dlmf.nist.gov/6.2.

Comment: Do you know the definition of $Ei$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Yes, I know the definition

Comment: And what happens when you change variables in your integral to $x = -2 \ln y$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Letting $u=2\ln y$ yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =\int \frac{e^{\frac{u}{2}}}{\frac{u}{2}} \cdot \frac{1}{2} e^{\frac{u}{2}} d u \\
& =\int \frac{e^u}{u} d u \\
& =E_i(u) +C\\
& =E_i(2 \ln y)+C
\end{aligned}
$$
where $E_i(.)$ is the Exponential Integral. The answer is **different** from OP’s and checked by [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint%20%5Cfrac%7By%7D%7B%5Cln%20y%7D%20d%20y) .

Comment: "The answer is different..." This is just a notational difference.  $\operatorname{Ei}(z)$ and $-\operatorname{Ei}_1(-z)$ both have derivative $e^z/z$.  Because of the definition, one of them is better suited for $z>0$, the other for $z<0$.

Answer (score 1):

$$y'y=\log(y)$$ Switch variables

$$\frac y{x'}=\log(y) \quad \implies \quad x'=\frac{y}{\log (y)}$$
$$x+c=\text{Ei}(2 \log (y))$$

Answer (score 1):

Let u=Iny. du=dy/y.  dy=ydu.  y=e^u
$ (e^u)/u × (e^u du)
$ (e^2u)/u × du. Let v=2u.  dv=2du.  U=v/2
$  (e^v)/(v/2) × dv/2
 $ (e^v)/v × dv = Ei(v)+C.   But v=2u and u=Iny
$ y/Iny × dy =Ei(2Iny)+C

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out from here, we can substitute $2u=r$ to turn the integral into$$\int\require{cancel}\cancel{\dfrac12\cdot2}\dfrac{e^r}rdr\gets\operatorname{Ei}(-r)+c_1$$and then undoing the substitutions gives us$$\operatorname{Ei}(-r)+c_1\gets\operatorname{Ei}(-2u)+c_1\gets\operatorname{Ei}(-2\ln y)+c_1$$

---

Notes on the diff. eq. (will remove if not needed)

---

As for the differential equation, it is not possible to isolate $y(x)$ due to $\operatorname{Ei}(x)$ not having an inverse that is representable using standard mathematical functions, however if we were to define $h(x)$ being the supposed inverse of $\operatorname{Ei}(x)$, the solution would be$$y(x)=e^{-0.5h(x+c_0+c_1)}$$however, it would probably just be best to say that the solution to the diff. eq. is just $x+c_0=\operatorname{Ei}(-2\ln y)$ again due to $\operatorname{Ei}(x)$ having no inverse in terms of standard mathematical functions.